# Why I am getting this error in zephir php extension development?

Tags: php-extension, zephir

PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/myapp.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/myapp.so: undefined symbol: zend_error_noreturn in Unknown on line 0

**My code (myapp.zep) is**

```
namespace Myapp;
class Greeting
{
    public static function test (string abc) {

                return "test back";
    }
}
```

The code worked when I remove the parameter

```
namespace Myapp;
class Greeting
{
    public static function test () {    //no parameter

                return "test back";
    }
}
```

When i set a parameter of method test with string abc then I got the error. But I compiled it in windows version it works fine..

My server configuration is

```
Centos 7.3 - 64bit 
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2017 07:57:06) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016  The PHP Group 
Zend Engine v2.6.0, 
Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

**I am totally stack now. This compiled .so file , I have used in another same configuration server, where it work fine.**

Comment: You need a dollar sign before your parameter name: `(string $abc)`

Comment: And you can't typehint strings prior to v7, so you'll need just: `($abc)`

Comment: Er wait, this isn't PHP is it, it's Zephir? They look practically the same.

Comment: Actually its zephir code. I think its like c++ language. It's PHP Extension development code using Zephir. However I have used that $ sign  too and got same error. Thank you

Comment: Yep ok, realized that at the same time heh. Just guessing, looks like maybe your version of Zephir requires a more recent version of PHP.

Comment: I think so.. But I have to build to php 5.6.30. I have no other option. The code is working in my Windows PHP 5.6.30 version but I got this problem in linux. I don't know why.

Comment: @AlexHowansky,  I am totally stack now. This compiled .so file , I have used in another same configuration server, where it work fine.